# how do you know the each parameter values of SDC at the first time?

Tags: synthesis, asic, soc, sdc

when we do synthesis with SDC. we should be used with SDC.
But I want to know what if you are in situation where the synthesis of yours is the first time, also the company does not even did synthesis before.
all of the first time, then your role and responsibility is make synthesis.

Ok, then how do you know the each SDC's commands parameters ? for example,

`set_clock_uncertainty -setup` ?

`set_clock_uncertainty -hold` ?

`set_clock_transition -rise -max` ?

`set_clock_transition -fall -min` ?

`set_input_delay` ?

`set_output_delay` ?

...?

when you first met this, how do you handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to learn all constraints used in SDC, from
[here](http://www.vlsi-expert.com/2011/02/synopsys-design-constraints-sdc-basics.html).

As you aware of all clocks frequency, so you just need to understand importance of each constraints and find out what optimum value should be correct.

Some constraints like `set_input_delay` and `set_output_delay` has standard value or generalized value like, `INPUT_DELAY_MARGIN` is 60% of your clock period and `OUTPUT_DELAY_MARGIN` is 40% of your clock period.

Set that value to parameter and then given to the `set_input_delay` and `set_output_delay` constraints.

```
set PERIOD_CLK               1    # 1 nSec is period of that clock

set INPUT_DELAY_MARGIN    0.60
set OUTPUT_DELAY_MARGIN   0.40 

set CLK_IN_DELAY [expr { $PERIOD_CLK * $INPUT_DELAY_MARGIN }]
set PCLK_OUT_DELAY  [expr { $PERID_PCLK * $OUTPUT_DELAY_MARGIN }]

# input delay is given to din_i pin/port
set_input_delay $CLK_IN_DELAY  -clock $CLK  [get_ports din_i]

# output delay is given to dout_o pin/port
set_output_delay $CLK_OUT_DELAY     -clock $CLK     [get_ports dout_o]
```

as you are doing STA on RTL stage, It is more of doing for CDC, lint checks only.

> > `set_clock_uncertenty` is 0.250 of clock period.
> >
> > `set_clock_transition` is two small, 0.1ps. [see this](http://free-online-ebooks.appspot.com/enc/14.17/fetxtcmdref/set_input_transition.html)

EDIT: places where STA performed,
[image]

Comment: Can you explain me why input is 60% and output 40%? not 40% and output 60%? Also how to set transition and skew values and set_clock_uncertenty value etc...? is there also too have standard value?

Comment: If you don't know the exact time for the signal to arrive at input port or output port, we will keep pessimistic value of 60 % to the external world and 40 % to the chip

Comment: At RTL level, you don't have standard delay format, and the environment where you put your design module and timing of then environment so the value assumed over here is all pessimistic values, and FYI STA is done at many stages where, you have all your assumption updated with actual values.

Comment: Prakash Darji : thanks,  but my question is what if my clock has 100Mhz then how do you set the other parameter coefficients value. for example set_clock_uncertaint, set_clock_latency, set_clock_transition -rise min/max ...

Comment: Yes, I have that answer too! wait for update

Comment: Oppps..., got it ;)

Comment: How do you got?

Comment: sure I'd like to accept. but let me know your experience. how do got that numbers.

Comment: That numbers are some what experimental analysis and then fixed up with average out worst case to normal case, when you go for next step of ASIC or FPGA flow you would come to know.

Comment: brother, I need more reputation to up vote. wait until then,

Comment: Its fine!! I can understand!!

Comment: can I ask you with off the topics about the SCAN ?

Comment: I am front end RTL design engineer, ask question, I'll try to answer surely. but you can rise new question too.